# How to run ActionListenters in two different thread for the following code

Tags: java, swing, awt, scope, actionlistener

I  made this program to play mp3 files in java.
 Following code plays the mp3 file but it can't stopped while playing...
I added two separate ActionListener to two buttons but it won't works for Stop button...

```
import java.io.*;    
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;



    public class Play2 extends JFrame
    {  
    JButton b,b1;
    JTextField t;

    Play2()
    {
        JFrame j=new JFrame("MusicPlayer");
        j.setSize(300,300);
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        b=new JButton("Play");
        b1=new JButton("Stop");
        JPanel p=new JPanel();
        t=new JTextField(20);
        p.add(t);
        p.add(b);
        p.add(b1);
        j.add(p);
        j.setVisible(true);


    }
    public void awt()
    {
    b.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                try  
                    {  

            String fname=t.getText();
            File directory = new File(fname);

            boolean isDirectory = directory.isDirectory();

            if (isDirectory) 
             {
                    // It returns true if directory is a directory.
                System.out.println("the name you have entered is a directory  : "  +  directory);  
                    //It returns the absolutepath of a directory.
                    System.out.println("the path is "  +  directory.getAbsolutePath());
             }
            else
            {
                    // It returns false if directory is a file.
                System.out.println("the name you have entered is a file  : " + directory);
                    //It returns the absolute path of a file.
                    System.out.println("the path is "  + directory.getAbsolutePath());
            }
                String s=directory.getAbsolutePath();

                s=s.replace("\\","/") ;

                    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(s);  
                    final Player playMp3=new Player(fis);  

                    playMp3.play(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);}
        }//end actionPerformed
      }//end ActionListener
    );//end addActionListener()

    b1.addActionListener(
      new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(
                                  ActionEvent ae){
          //Terminate playback before EOF
                    try  
                    {  

            String fname=t.getText();
            File directory = new File(fname);

            boolean isDirectory = directory.isDirectory();

            if (isDirectory) 
             {
                    // It returns true if directory is a directory.
                System.out.println("the name you have entered is a directory  : "  +  directory);  
                    //It returns the absolutepath of a directory.
                    System.out.println("the path is "  +  directory.getAbsolutePath());
             }
            else
            {
                    // It returns false if directory is a file.
                System.out.println("the name you have entered is a file  : " + directory);
                    //It returns the absolute path of a file.
                    System.out.println("the path is "  + directory.getAbsolutePath());
            }
                String s=directory.getAbsolutePath();

                s=s.replace("\\","/") ;

                    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(s);  
                    final Player playMp3=new Player(fis);  

                    playMp3.close(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);}
        }//end actionPerformed
      }//end ActionListener
    );//end addActionListener()

    }


        public static void main(String[]args)  
        {  
        Play2 f=new Play2();
        f.awt();    
    }

}
```

Comment: `final Player playMp3=new Player(fis);  

                    playMp3.play();`  The `playMp3` should be declared as an attribute of the class that is available to whatever methods need it,  e.g. a `start()` or `stop()` method.

Comment: Please use a consistent and coherent indentation. As it stands, your code is rather hard to read (and very much error-prone)!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is hogging the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) with your play button listener.

When you click the Play button, an ActionEvent will be posted to the Event Queue. If you subsequently press your Stop button, another ActionEvent will be posted to the EventQueue.

The EDT will start processing the first event in the Event Queue (the play event). In that event, you invoke the `play()` method on the (mp3) `Player` class on EDT. The `play()` method keeps on looping until the entire mp3 has been played. During this whole time, the other event (the stop event) will be waiting in the Event Queue for its turn to be executed. So when it finally becomes the stop event's turn to execute, the mp3 has already been played until the end, and the stop command is rather redundant.

---

**The main problem:** You should not execute lengthy tasks on the EDT.

**A solution:** Ensure that the play method is executed on a non-EDT thread by using the [SwingWorker class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to invoke the `Player.play()` method.

**Reference**: [Event-Dispatch Thread Rules for Swing UIs (online article)](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/7717) (It might be interesting for you to read this. Particularly the information in the **Never Delay the EDT** section, which contains info about this particular issue)